# Which will use less memory - multiple object variables, or a single function that can return any one of the same objects when needed?

Tags: javascript, function, object, memory

I'm creating an app that will use about 10 to 15 JSON objects as factory data that the user can then modify and persist to their device. Given the size of these objects I'm concerned about memory overhead. So I'm thinking instead of using multiple object variables in memory like this:

```
let rsOne = {};
let rsTwo = {};
let rsThree = {};
let rsFour = {};
let rsFive = {};
```

...would it use less memory to use a single function that returns any one of the same objects only when needed, like this:

```
let getRS = function(rsName) {
    switch(rsName) {
        case 'rsOne':
            return {};
        case 'rsTwo':
            return {};
        case 'rsThree':
            return {};
        case 'rsFour':
            return {};
        case 'rsFive':
            return {};
    }
};
```

Comment: The second will use less memory. In the first, you are declaring and instantiating 5 objects, whereas in the second example you only instantiate an object when you hit the return; the other 4 aren't hit

Comment: Thanks, Kobe, I appreciate your input. I was thinking the same thing but I wasn't sure if the javascript engine would parse out the objects in the function and store them in memory given that they're object literals and not something the function has to compute.